# FLTK: Clearing a graph when drawing another

Tags: c++, fltk

I wrote a simple FLTK program to draw a circle when clicking on the "Draw Circle" button and to draw a line when clicking on the "Draw Line" button. I supposed to have only one graph. But I got two graphs in the panel. I want only one showing and the other disappearing. The following is the code:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <FL/fl_draw.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

using namespace std;

int flag = 0;
class Drawing : public Fl_Box {
    void draw() {
        fl_color(255, 0, 0);
        int x, y, x1, y1;
        if (flag == 1) {
            
            double radius = 100;
            x = (int)(w() / 2);
            y = (int)(h() / 2);
            fl_circle(x, y, radius);
        }
        else if (flag == -1) {
            
            x = (int)(w() / 4);
            y = (int)(h() / 4);
            x1 = (int)(w() *3/ 4);
            y1 = (int)(h() *3/ 4);
            fl_line(x, y, x1, y1);
        }
    }
public:
    Drawing(int X, int Y, int W, int H) : Fl_Box(X, Y, W, H) {}
};

Drawing* d;

void circle_cb(Fl_Widget*, void*) {
    flag = 1;
    fl_overlay_clear();
    d->redraw();
} // end sumbit_cb

void line_cb(Fl_Widget*, void*) {
    flag = -1;
    fl_overlay_clear();
    d->redraw();
} // end clear_cb

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Fl_Window* window = new Fl_Window(600, 550); // create a window, originally(400,400)

    Drawing dr(0, 0, 600, 600);
    d = &dr;

    Fl_Button *b, *c;

    b = new Fl_Button(150, 80, 100, 25, "&Draw Circle");
    b->callback(circle_cb);

    c = new Fl_Button(350, 80, 100, 25, "&Draw Line");
    c->callback(line_cb);

    window->end(); //show the window 
    window->show(argc, argv);
    return Fl::run();
}
```

I have used fl_overlay_clear() to clear graph. However it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues that need to be fixed in your program, but first of all using the draw() method as you did is basically correct. However, using fl_overlay_clear(); is useless, you can remove it.

My solution: your widget doesn't have a solid background (boxtype), i.e. your draw method draws over the background over and over again w/o clearing it. There are several ways to solve this, but if you want to learn what happens, try this first: add `window->resizable(window);` before `window->show(argc, argv);`, run the program again and resize the window. You'll notice that the previous drawing disappears and only one drawing stays. That's because the background is cleared when you resize the widget.

Next step: add a solid boxtype:

```cpp
  d = &dr;
  d->box(FL_DOWN_BOX);
```

and add `Fl_Box::draw();` right at the beginning of your `draw()` method.

If you do that you may notice that your button(s) disappear when you click one of them - because your buttons are **inside** the area of your `Drawing`. The last thing(s) I fixed was to correct the coordinates of buttons and to enlarge the window (it was too small anyway to cover the entire `Drawing`). Here's my complete result:

```cpp
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <FL/fl_draw.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

using namespace std;

int flag = 0;
class Drawing : public Fl_Box {
  void draw() {
    Fl_Box::draw();
    fl_color(255, 0, 0);
    int x, y, x1, y1;
    if (flag == 1) {

      double radius = 100;
      x = (int)(w() / 2);
      y = (int)(h() / 2);
      fl_circle(x, y, radius);
    } else if (flag == -1) {

      x = (int)(w() / 4);
      y = (int)(h() / 4);
      x1 = (int)(w() * 3 / 4);
      y1 = (int)(h() * 3 / 4);
      fl_line(x, y, x1, y1);
    }
  }

public:
  Drawing(int X, int Y, int W, int H)
    : Fl_Box(X, Y, W, H) {}
};

Drawing *d;

void circle_cb(Fl_Widget *, void *) {
  flag = 1;
  // fl_overlay_clear();                       // not useful
  d->redraw();
} // end sumbit_cb

void line_cb(Fl_Widget *, void *) {
  flag = -1;
  // fl_overlay_clear();                       // not useful
  d->redraw();
} // end clear_cb

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(600, 660); // create a window, originally(400,400)

  Drawing dr(0, 60, 600, 600);                        // FIXED
  d = &dr;
  d->box(FL_DOWN_BOX);                                // ADDED

  Fl_Button *b, *c;

  b = new Fl_Button(150, 20, 100, 25, "&Draw Circle"); // FIXED
  b->callback(circle_cb);

  c = new Fl_Button(350, 20, 100, 25, "&Draw Line");   // FIXED
  c->callback(line_cb);

  window->end(); // show the window
  window->resizable(window);              // ADDED
  window->show(argc, argv);
  return Fl::run();
}
```

I believe this does what you want.

PS: the official FLTK support forum can be found on our website https://www.fltk.org/ and the direct link to the user forum (Google Groups) is https://groups.google.com/g/fltkgeneral

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick addition to what Albrecht put so perfectly: FLTK drawing coordinates are relative to the window, not relative to the widget. You probably want to offset your drawing by the `x()` and `y()` coordinates of your widget.

Comment: Good catch. I must have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In your handle() methods `line_cb()` , `circle_cb()` should call `window()->make_current()` and then `fl_overlay_rect()` after `FL_DRAG` events, and should call `fl_overlay_clear()` after a `FL_RELEASE event`. [Refer](http://fltk.org/doc-1.3/drawing.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Could you put more in details?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that this answer is helpful because the OP uses the virtual draw() method of the class correctly. I'll post another answer.